# Docker compose can not create container for postgresql and redis

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a problem with `docker-compose` and can not create containers for service `postgresql` and `redis`, after I run `docker-compose up -d` I've got this error:

```
ERROR: for dockerizingdjango_postgres_1  Cannot create container for service postgres: b'invalid port specification: "None"'
Creating dockerizingdjango_redis_1 ... 
Creating dockerizingdjango_redis_1 ... error
ERROR: for dockerizingdjango_redis_1  Cannot create container for service redis: b'invalid port specification: "None"'
ERROR: for postgres  Cannot create container for service postgres: b'invalid port specification: "None"'
ERROR: for redis  Cannot create container for service redis: b'invalid port specification: "None"'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - redis:redis
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  environment:
    DEBUG: 'true'
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

apache:
  restart: always
  build: ./apache/
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - /www/static
    - /www/media
  volumes_from:
    - web
  links:
    - web:web

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

redis:
  restart: always
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - redisdata:/data
```

I'm using this version of `docker-compose`:

```
docker-compose version 1.13.0, build 1719ceb
docker-py version: 2.3.0
CPython version: 3.4.3
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

also I'm using `python3.5` for this container, because I'm serving django in this container, so can someone help me and explain what is going on here, and how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: Did you see this issue ? https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4729

Comment: the issue was solved with me installing [docker-compose](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-16-04), after reading this blog post, `pip` installation was giving me a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are hitting this issue(https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4729). Workaround as mentioned in link is to downgrade compose or upgrade python.